# Fragment activity crashes on screen rotate

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a simple fragment activity. In the onCreate() method, I simply add a fragment. The code is posted below. However, each time I rotate the screen, system will call onCreate() again, then it crashes at the super.onCreate() statement; I suppose it is a general Android fragment issue. Can someone help me out?

```
public class FragActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState){
        super.onCreate(savedState);

        MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, frag)
        .commit();        
    }
}
```

The stack trace is attached:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: 
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to
>   instantiate fragment:  make sure class name exists, is public, and has
>   an empty constructor that is public

Comment: And your fragment has a public empty constructor ?

Comment: Tough to say without the whole stack trace.  (Those three lines are only part of it.)  Probably safest to post a healthy chunk of the log surrounding the stack trace, too, in case there's something of interest in there.  What's the onCreate method of your Fragment look like?

Comment: Are you referencing your Fragment subclass from a layout file? Do you have different layout files for Portrait and Landscape?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, as you error says, something is wrong with your MyFragment class. Make sure you have something like:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
```

when declaring your fragment class. Also, you shouldn't have any constructor in the class. So make sure that you don't have one.

If you post the code for your Fragment class we might be able to help you better.

Comment: Thanx all for the help.

The structure of fragment classes and fragment activity class is like:

In source file MyActivity.java,





------------
public class MyActivity extend FragmentActivity{
...
}
class MyFragment extends Fragment{
...
}

------------------





MyFragment is a non-public class in the same source file, it causes the app crashes on rotating display. By putting MyFragment class into MyActivity class as an inner class, it solves the issue.

Thanx all.

Comment: Jimmy, like I said in my response. You need to make MyFragment is public. Otherwise things won't work.

Comment: Right, of course.
Sorry I missed that.
Actually I put MyFragment class as an inner public static class of MyActivity class, it worked.

Thanx again.

Comment: thx kurtis, i have the same problem and the solution is as you said  ", you shouldn't have any constructor in the class"

Comment: I have crashes sometimes on resume (without rotation). My fragment is a public top level class, but I have and need constructors. Or how I pass initialization data? do I have to make custom init method? Or is it enough just to also add the default contructor?

Comment: But if it's called by the framework how do I pass the initialization data?

Comment: @Ixx to pass arguments to a fragment, use the setArguments function.

Comment: "**you shouldn't have any constructor in the class**" -  is this correct? I mean, I suppose we can have constructors in the class, but we need to have also an empty constructor. The error is clear to me: **make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public**. What do you guys think?

Comment: This just saved my ass, all because I declared my Fragment as `class MyFrag ...` instead of `public class MyFrag ...`.

Answer (score 8):

Your Fragment shouldn't have constructors because of how the FragmentManager instantiate it. 
You should have a `newInstance()` static method defined and pass any parameters via arguments (bundle)

For example:

```
public static final MyFragment newInstance(int title, String message)
{
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(2);
    bundle.putInt(EXTRA_TITLE, title);
    bundle.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment ;
}
```

And read these arguments at onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    title = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_TITLE);
    message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //...

}
```

This way if detached and re-attached the object state can be stored through the arguments, much like bundles attached to Intents.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem when I renamed my project package name. The fragment class is referred by xml layout and usually contains the full package name.Thats where the problem was. My fragment class name was still having old package name.

Answer (score 1):

The Fragment class also should not be an inner class, because it is instantiated out of your Activity class scope.
Nested class is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
static
```

Fixed it for me

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
```