# Activity crashes on screen rotation caused by fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an activity that hosts 4 fragements in it. On screen rotate, the activity crashes saying the following:

```
04-01 16:43:46.670: E/AndroidRuntime(2401): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.activity.FragmentActivity$UserFragment; no empty constructor
04-01 16:43:46.670: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-01 16:43:46.670: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-01 16:43:46.670: E/AndroidRuntime(2401):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
```

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058809/fragment-activity-crashes-on-screen-rotate) which says the fragment class must be declared public. It is declared public and it does not resolve the problem.

Following is the code I have:

```
public class FragmentActivity extends Activity
{
    public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
    {
        private Fragment mFragment;

        public TabListener(Fragment fragment)
        {
           mFragment = fragment;
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
           ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, mFragment, null);
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
           ft.remove(mFragment);
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
        }
    }

    public class UserFragment extends Fragment
    {
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
         .....
         ..... 
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container);

       ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
       actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
       Tab userTab = actionBar.newTab();
       userTab.setIcon(R.drawable.person).setTabListener(new TabListener(new UserFragment()));
       actionBar.addTab(userTab);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

UserFragment must be a static nested class in order to be re-instantiated:

```
public static class UserFragment extends Fragment { 
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding **android:launchMode="singleTask"** to the AndroidManifest.xml.

Example:

```
   <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Tried it. Did not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an empty constructor for the fragment

```
public class UserFragment extends Fragment { 
     public UserFragment(){}
     ....
}
```

Comment: Nah, this is not going to help.

Answer (score 1):

Joe is right. You need to declare the inner Fragment class static to separate it from a instance of its encapsulating class or declare it in its own .java file.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add to UserFragment class an emty constructor:

```
public class UserFragment extends Fragment
{
   public UserFragment(){}

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
     .....
     ..... 
   }
}
```

2) Be sure that UserFragment class is a separate class (not in FragmentActivity class) and in separate *.java file (Ex: UserFragment.java)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code it looks like you have defined all your fragments in the same class instead just create separate class file for each fragment.

that worked for me as a charm